# Как вывести метки всех записей на карте гугл при помощи произвольных полей?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленной темой *classipress*. В теме для каждой записи или объявления можно задавать координаты места положения на гугл карте с помощью заполнения произвольных полей `cp_street,cp_city,cp_state,cp_zipcode`. А я хочу вывести карту с указанием всех меток с адресами записей - как это сделать? Кручу-верчу, но пока не получается.

**Код ниже** позволяет вывести координату только одной метки записи

```
<div id="gmap" class="mapblock">
  <?php
    $make_address = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_street', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_city', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_state', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true );
    $coordinates = cp_get_geocode( $post->ID );
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">var address = "<?php echo esc_js($make_address); ?>";</script>
  <?php cp_google_maps_js( $coordinates ); ?>
  <!-- google map div -->
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<?php function cp_google_maps_js( $coordinates ) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        map_init();
    });
    <?php
    if ( ! empty( $coordinates ) && is_array( $coordinates ) ) {
      echo 'var SavedLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(' . $coordinates['lat'] . ', ' . $coordinates['lng'] . ');';
      $location_by = "'latLng':SavedLatLng";
      $marker_position = "SavedLatLng";
    } else {
      $location_by = "'address': address";
      $marker_position = "results[0].geometry.location";
    }
    ?>
    var map = null;
    var marker = null;
    var infowindow = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var fromAdd;
    var toAdd;
    var redFlag = "<?php echo esc_js( appthemes_locate_template_uri( 'images/red-flag.png' ) ); ?>";
    var noLuck = "<?php echo esc_js( appthemes_locate_template_uri( 'images/gmaps-no-result.gif' ) ); ?>";
    var adTitle = "<?php echo esc_js( get_the_title() ); ?>";
    var contentString = '<div id="mcwrap"><span>' + adTitle + '</span><br />' + address + '</div>';

    function map_init() {
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#map').hide();
        load();
        $('#map').fadeIn(1000);
        codeAddress();
      });
    }
    function load() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: newyork,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            }
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
    }
    function codeAddress() {
        geocoder.geocode( { <?php echo $location_by; ?> }, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: redFlag,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: <?php echo $marker_position; ?>
            });

            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 230,
                content: contentString,
                disableAutoPan: false
            });

            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            (function($) {
                $('#map').html('<div style="height:400px;background: url(' + noLuck + ') no-repeat center center;"><p style="padding:50px 0;text-align:center;"><?php echo esc_js( __( 'Sorry, the address could not be found.', APP_TD ) ); ?></p></div>');
                return false;
            })(jQuery);
          }
        });
      }

    function showAddress(fromAddress, toAddress) {
        calcRoute();
        calcRoute1();
    }
    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("fromAdd").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("toAdd").value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Собрать все координаты меток в массив, выдать его в js, в джсе нагенерить меток.

Comment: @u_mulder а можно подробнее 2 и 3 часть - как раз с этим у меня проблемы. Даже если просто второй раз вызываю функцию с уже другими координатами `cp_google_maps_js( $coordinates );` результат сыплется..

Comment: А что поподробнее - функция получает все координаты, выводит в страницу джсон-енкодом, далее работает джаваскрипт. И да, вызывается она один раз.

Comment: @u_mulder ну вот собрал я массив `$posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post'));
foreach($posts as $post){ 
 $address = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_street', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_city', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_state', true ) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true );
}` и как теперь его передать в функцию и разложить на метки?